# How do I make join table entries unique?

Tags: mysql

I know how to make an [individual column entry](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) unique, but I want to make two columns together unique. I have a join table of votes. Each vote has a userId and a messageId. Every vote is an entry into this table. I do not want to allow a user to vote more than once on a single message. What constraint can I add to this join table to make it so each user can only vote on each message or comment once?

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  messageString text NOT NULL,
  image varchar(255) DEFAULT 'NULL',
  score int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  commentString text NOT NULL,
  messageId int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id)
);

CREATE TABLE votes (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  messageId int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  commentId int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES comments(id)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  token VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(token)
);
```

Comment: just create a unique key across `(userToken, messageId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove `votes.id` and use `PRIMARY KEY (userToken, messageId)`, or use `PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE KEY (userToken, messageId)` if you think you absolutely need an `id`.

(Not sure what `commentId` is though, couldn't figure it out from your explanation; maybe you'll need to add that to the composite index as well.)